# IP v6 address socket creation fails with “Unable to create SSL socket” error

Tags: cassandra

IP v6 address socket creation fails with “Unable to create SSL socket” error:

```
Unable to create ssl socket
Fatal configuration error; unable to start server.  See log for stacktrace.
10:31:36.165 [main] ERROR o.a.c.service.CassandraDaemon - Fatal configuration error
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Unable to create ssl socket
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.getServerSockets(MessagingService.java:521) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.listen(MessagingService.java:501) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.listen(MessagingService.java:485) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:745) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:648) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:548) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:385) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:601) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:730) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at org.apache.cassandra.security.SSLFactory.getServerSocket(SSLFactory.java:65) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.getServerSockets(MessagingService.java:517) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        ... 8 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Not an expert in this domain but what commad did you run that gave you this error? Or what button did you press?

Answer (score 3):

You need to comment out the following line in the file */etc/cassandra/jvm.options*

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

As Simon mentioned in an answer below, you may need to uncomment or edit properties in cassandra.yaml also.

```
rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6=true
listen_interface_prefer_ipv6=true
```

That should fix the issue.  For more details check [this](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/207433496-Unable-to-connect-to-DSE-via-native-protocol-over-IPv6) link.

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek Garg! But still getting same error with below steps:
1. cassandra-env.sh
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true"
2. cassandra.yaml
listen_address: 2001::::::xxx
#listen_interface: ens32
listen_interface_prefer_ipv6: true
rpc_address: 2001::::::xxx
#rpc_interface: ens32
rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6: true

3. changed ipv6 forwarding
vi /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 0
sysctl -p

Comment: you need to modify in /etc/cassandra/jvm.options  not in cassandra-env.sh. I mentioned this in my answer, it has updated after Cassandra 3.2

Comment: ya now i found out jvm.options available under CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/jvm.options, even after changing that facing same error, is there any specific way i need to feed the IPV6 address in cassandra.yaml? I mean with square brackets or within double quotes?

Comment: So you modified CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/jvm.options by uncommenting -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  and you also uncommented rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6=true
listen_interface_prefer_ipv6=true in cassandra.yaml and after doing that you are still facing the exact same error?

Comment: Yes, still same error, thats why suspecting the way IPv6 address feeded in cassandra.yaml file.Could you throw some light on how IPv6 address should be feeded in yaml file.

Comment: Try adding listen and broadcast address with "" quotes. Also, run systemctl restart httpd before starting Cassandra

Comment: problem is with the ssl storage port 7001, i see at this point its failing:
 INFO  o.a.cassandra.net.MessagingService - Starting Encrypted Messaging Service on SSL port 7001 ( Working for ipv4)
if its in ipv6, the above error occuring, so is it possible to map the ipv6 address to this storage port.

Answer (score 1):

As Abhishek says you need to change a line in jvm.options:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false
```

Also, in cassandra.yaml file you need to uncomment and set the following options:

```
rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6=true
listen_interface_prefer_ipv6=true
```